# Code editors arent recognizing javascript functions

Tags: javascript

Hi so ive tried to set up a terminal in Atom and in Visual code but it doesnt work and its really bugging me.

ive tried the 'extension: terminal' and built in terminal to run JavaScript,
as well as the atom 'script' extension.

here is an example of my dilemma

1) If i try to run some basic code like

```
let x = 'string';
console.log(x);
```

My output is:

```
string
```

2) Or if i try something like

```
console.log(fetch('https://regres.in/api/users'));
```

my output is

```
console.log(fetch('https://regres.in/api/users'));
    ^

ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
```

3) even something as simple as

```
document.getElementById('element');
```

this will return

```
document is not defined.
```

It seems like its not recoginizing any methods? like .fetch() or even the document selector. I know this is probably some noob mistake im making but I couldnt find a way to work my question in google so im asking for some help, thanks!

Comment: When running from the terminal things like window, document and other client side objects can not be used. `fetch()` is another method that isn't accessible from the terminal. The atom or VSCode terminal are running the code as if it is a node js application and therefore, document, window and others like them are not accessible/usable.

Comment: It looks like it's treating the file as a NodeJS file, as node will not have access to the `document` object as well as the browser `console`, since it does not run in a browser.

Comment: What `document` are you even trying to reference?

Comment: So if this is the case and it wont be possible in these editors, is there a web based terminal that I can use to test the outputs? Or what do most people use

Comment: Yes, press f12 while on chrome to open the google chrome console

Comment: @ChristopherLopez, can you confirm that this is, in fact, code that you're running on the server via NodeJS and not on the browser?

Comment: Got it working by just looking at it in chrome! Thanks guys really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Like what was said in the comments, fetch, window, and document are client-side methods/objects and can not be accessed from Node JS run terminals like the ones from VSCode and Atom. I believe what you are looking for is a browser equivalent to the terminal, which would be the console. To access it on chrome you can use <kbd>ctrl + shift + i</kbd>  or press <kbd>f12</kbd> or right click on the page and press inspect. This will open the inspection tools, navigate to the console.

Here are some pictures to help:[image]
[image]

I hope this helps.